# how to send the output to a logfile and richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, output

I have the follow code that works for sending the output to a richtextbox. I cant figure out how to also have the output sent to a log file if I choose as well. this is the beginnings of my code for choosing to log the output. I cant figure out how to get it to log the output to the file location.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox31.Text = Chr(34) & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & Chr(34)
    End If
    End Sub
```

here is my working code for displaying the output in the richtextbox.

```
    Private Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Dim myprocess As New Process
    Dim startinfo As New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox3.Text, TextBox1.Text) With {
        .UseShellExecute = False,
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
        .CreateNoWindow = True
    }
    myprocess.StartInfo = startinfo
    myprocess.Start()
    Dim str1 As String = ""
    Using MyStreamReader As IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
        str1 &= MyStreamReader.ReadToEnd
    End Using
    RichTextBox1.Text = str1
End Sub
```

Note: This is what I used to be able to log the output

```
     If CheckBox34.Checked = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(TextBox31.Text & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & ".log", True)
        objWriter.WriteLine(Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ") & TextBox4.Text & vbCrLf & str1)
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Use a StreamWriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With this sample:

```
    Dim MyPath = "C:\MyLog.Log"
    FileOpen(1, MyPath, OpenMode.Append)
    Dim lNumberofRecs = LOF(1)
    Print(1, Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "#Import Begin" & vbCrLf)
    FileClose(1)
```

or with this:

```
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\MyData\mylog.log", True)
    objWriter.WriteLine("each log data you have")
    objWriter.Close()
```

Comment: I haven't seen code like that first block in a very long time. New code would certainly use .net methods. The StreamWriter requires that .Dispose is called. A Using block will accomplish this.

Comment: I made a small tweak to the second suggestion to make the filename be the "date".log. See the edited original post.